# M2 - Decrypt Data Block command failed

Tags: hsm

I am facing problem with DUKPT Decryption. I am sending the Decrypt Data Block (M2) command as per THales HSM manual, but I am getting error response as: 0000M315

Please find command below, Request you to help me whats wrong with my command.

**COMMAND:** `0000M20011009U3BEE6C2C1850D691299B843984177A9A609FFFFFF8500000600016200E0beb0297d81e42bf9e07b1948dfaba7f8f032622173f61d2bacf6f485fa0a9babaf58637184b5e459cbae55f2b53ff9c356e4817f2efa9d70e740b27e2e089ccf42fefa56ee38c58d49f89206f9709c31e7ec616767f7638e3f853dde45af94e7cdb06502017a16c44ab472c3ce03260e`

Thanks,
Nazir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, I have just changed data to upper case.

Thanks,
Nazir

Comment: Dear Nazir, I am trying to use M2 to decrypt our encrypted data. For M2's input we have: Key - The decryption Key, used in conjunction with the IV, if appropriate, to decrypt the supplied Message. Can you tell me the value for it is a variant, encrypted from LMK?

Thanks a lot friend.